# ASP.NET Get all checkboxs from Repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkbox, controls

I used repeater to generate checkbox in a Content page,

both checkbox has a unique ID,

However, the checkboxs were generated by looping the string

```
<input id=\"Checkbox" + i+ "-" + j + "\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"CollapseID" + i + "\" />
```

It can properly show in the webpage, with correct ID, and its name. 
Moreover, I can control it via javascript.

I would like to ask, how can I know those checkbox is checked or not in server side?

I have tried using the below code, but return null.

```
foreach (Control control in this.Page.Form.Controls)  
{  
    if (control is CheckBox)  
    {  
        string checkboxValue = ((CheckBox)control).Text;  
    }
}
```

Also, I tried:

```
Control chk = FindControl("Checkbox1-1"); // where "Checkbox1-1" is the checkboxID
```

and

```
HtmlInputCheckBox chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)FindControl("Checkbox1-1");
```

but also return null...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are creating these checkboxes using string and then dumping them as HTML. they will be treated as html check boxes and will not be accessible at server side. you can get selected checkboxes in javascript only.. you can assign those values to any hidden server control and then use that in server side.

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is my only way...
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you should write attribute as `runat="server"` in checkbox.

then

```
CheckBox cx= repeaterName.FindControl("checkboxId") as CheckBox;
```

I think it will work for you.